# Unsupported or Unrecognized array type error in OpenCV 3.1 in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.1

Okay, there have been questions about this here and I've tried all of them - but none has worked for me.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('circleTest.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20, param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
# draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
# draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code is borrowed from a [tutorial about HoughCircles](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html). Whenever I try to run the code I get an error saying

> Unsupported or Unrecognized array type, ( you must have seen the entire error).

I tried copying DLLs, putting the image in the working directory, giving the path to the image but no good. I can run other programs like of object detection fine, on Python and C/C++.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: OpenCV Logo as example picture]

I can run a slightly modified code without problems using the opencv logo above as input picture.

Your original code had a missing indentation in the circles loop which I have corrected.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('circleTest.jpg')
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

gimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gimg,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=10,maxRadius=50)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
# draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
# draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Resulting image:
[image]

[EDIT] I have modified my code so that it works on your original image. The only thing I have done is restricting search radius vales to ,minRadius=10,maxRadius=50. I do not know what you are looking for, I don't see that many circles :-)

Comment: Missing indentation? You mean the hough transform line broke up into 2 parts? I made it into a single line and tried my code but no luck. And yeah I'm sorry about the picture, I posted it in such a hurry that I forgot the picture itself, here's it- https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EEABAA7CDCB08F75!29989&authkey=!AOIl5VBnlm_prIg&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg   Thanks!

Comment: I got the code to work, there was some indentation problem inside the for loop. I can run your image, and another jpg opencv logo image but when I try to run my image, the program just sits and does nothing. @tfv

Comment: I did not wait for execution to come to an end on your original image, but it worked after I resized your image to 25% with Irfanview. I get loads of circles in that, however, so it is still slow. Try reducing your image size, this might allow you fine tuning parameters.

Comment: I was looking for the red traffic light in the image... When I ran the program, it only detected a hell lot of false circles near the top left corner of the image. How do I get that traffic light. Note that this image is quite different from the one that I'm making the program to run on. The program is intended to run and find a traffic light 2m ahead of the camera, while working from a video feed from the webcam. @tfv

Comment: I wrote the code again from scratch. I got it working but its not detecting the intended circle. I am now using - `circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 500)`  Here is the image pinpointing the circle I need - https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EEABAA7CDCB08F75!29991&authkey=!AJ_H7UclA5DENEI&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng . And here is the new cropped image - https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EEABAA7CDCB08F75!29990&authkey=!AMhIaniJTUmWsjA&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: But since the issue of this post is solved, I'll close it